# Extract DRL from DSLR

Tags: xml, jboss, drools

How can I access the DRL generated within a DSLR file in Drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSLs are just preprocessed DRL.  I think the following link gives you an example on how to get DRL out of a DSLR.

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/DrlParserTest.java

Kris